# found error: Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter on jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins, ant

1. I have written an ant file  in module1, which compiles the java classes and creates jar file
2. ant file works fine locally on my machine using Eclipse Ant Launcher, only  when we set the run configuration as Run in the Same JRE as the workspace.
3. If Separate JRE is selected I get this error.
   Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter
4. Once I commit, Jenkins job is failing with the same  error:
   Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter

Analysis : I think JRE configuration is not set of module1 in jenkin server .

How I can configured the module1 according to JRE in Jenkins.

Please gives your valuable suggestion on this issue.